# Следует ли править неинформативные заголовки вопросов?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, правки

**Дано:**

Часто встречаются вопросы (в основном от новичков) вида "[Помощь в парсинге сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/453354/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0)". При этом сам текст вопроса может быть вполне полезен, если за автора сформулировать вопрос.

**Вопрос:**

Таки править заголовок, не реагировать или нещадно удалять вопрос?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Да, конечно стоит:

- Чтобы помочь отвечающим распознать вопрос в общей массе
- Чтобы помочь будущим читателям найти вопрос
- Чтобы немного научить автора вопроса формулировать мысли

Comment: Мне иногда не хватает филологического образования, не то чтобы  релевантно сформулировать заголовок вопроса, но и даже поисковый запрос в гугл или яндекс. Я благодарен редакторам, которые правят мои заголовки, иногда я сам понимаю что недостаточно чётко указал заголовок, и прошу исправить его. Иногда редактирую заголовок после получения правильного ответа.

Comment: @Shilgen: задача текста вопроса, чтобы люди с похожей проблемой могли его в поисковике найти. Если ваш вопрос отредактируют так, что он будет идеален, если знать ответ, но будет препятствовать людям, которые не знают ответ, его найти, то такую правку следует откатить. ~95% трафика из поисковиков: вопрос должен использовать термины, которые знают люди с тем же вопросом (а не те термины, которые знают люди, которые могут ответить на вопрос). [~95% трафика из поисковиков на Stack Overflow](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7374/23044)

Answer (score 5):

Это зависит от "неинформативности" заголовка.

Например, если весь заголовок *"Срочно! Помогите!"*, то следует редактировать или сразу удалить, если сам вопрос не спасти.

На другой строне спектра следует помнить, что пространство решений и пространство проблем могут иметь разные словари и разные люди могут формулировать одну и ту же проблему, используя разные слова.

**Правильная формулировка вопроса часто бывает половиной решения.**

Например, вопрос ["Вызов переменной из функции"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/453718/23044) фактически спрашивает "как добавить кнопку к новому окну в tkinter", что ведёт к очевидному ответу. Маловероятно, что автор вопроса, столкнувшись с проблемой, стал бы искать вопрос с переименованным заголовком -- иначе *не было бы необходимости задавать вопрос в первую очередь*, если человек уже понимает взаимотношение имён и объектов, на которые они ссылаются, в Питоне.

Ещё пример: ["Запуск программы на python из командной строки"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/439533/23044), который можно озаглавить "Имеют ли значение пробелы между путями в %PATH% переменной окружения в Windows" c очевидным ответом. Снова, существование ответа на вопрос о `%PATH%`, не помогло бы автору напрямую.

Это явление также объясняет почему вопросы-дубликаты не удаляются, а сохраняются в качестве ориентиров для будущих посетителей. Например, [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/4279) имеет [более **двух сотен** дубликатов.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/1132941) Вот [SEDE запрос, чтобы найти вопросы с большим кол-вом дубликатов](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/254033/rampant-duplicates-questions-with-the-most-duplicates). Можно посмотреть на разнообразие как разные люди один и тот же вопрос задают.

> А что если оригинальный заголовок переместить в тело вопроса? Тогда сохранится возможность поиска по "наивному" запросу, но и будет точная формулировка для тех, кто знает, что искать.

В интерфейсе сайта, только заголовки в подсказке. Если вопрос полезный -- его спросят неоднократно. Если назойливые дубликаты расплодятся, то можно канонический вопрос найти (с заголовком наиболее близким к словарю из пространства решений), а всё остальное позакрывать как дубликаты.

Comment: А что если оригинальный заголовок переместить в тело вопроса? Тогда сохранится возможность поиска по "наивному" запросу, но и будет точная формулировка для тех, кто знает, что искать.

Comment: Про мой комментарий — только сейчас прочитал дополнение. Пожалуй, вы правы.

Comment: Сослался на этот ответ. Если вам есть что добавить там, то, пожалуйста, добавьте. [Надо ли вообще улучшать вопросы-дубликаты?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/2314)

Answer (score 4):

В части повторного использования ответов (решения своей проблемы через поиск на ресурсе) - заголовок основной критерий отбора пригодности вопроса в решении проблемы, так как именно он виден полностью в поисковой выдаче и вообще при поиске читают именно заголовки в первую очередь. Что-то вроде: "Ничего не пойму, какая-то ошибка. Помогите!!" тут совершенно неприемлемо.

Поэтому заголовок должен максимально точно отражать суть вопроса. Если автор не смог достаточно точно сформулировать проблему, решение которой ему требуется, а сам вопрос достаточно полезен для других пользователей, то заголовок нужно обязательно привести в пригодный вид. Это пойдет на пользу целям ресурса и сильно облегчит работу тем, кто будет искать решение своей проблемы.