# Как проверить, не является ли вопрос дубликатом?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, дубликаты

Как быстро проверить, не является ли новый вопрос дубликатом уже имеющегося? 
Что следует делать, если является?
Я здесь новичок, и не очень хорошо еще ориентируюсь, но замысел (SO на русском) мне очень нравится и я хотел бы понемногу приносить пользу. Ветеранам напомню ощущение новичка (думаю, довольно типичное): не хватает компактно изложенных рекомендаций относительно того, что полезного можно сделать, и как именно это следует делать.

Comment: воспользоваться поиском например

Comment: Также справа от вопроса есть столбец «Похожие», можете искать и там.

Comment: Ага, спасибо. Я думал, может какое ноухау есть, которого я не нашел по неопытности. Но вторая часть вопроса - что делать с дублями - остается, хотелось бы услышать ответы.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Напишите вопрос, создайте заголовок, который кратко суть проблемы, как вы её понимаете, отражает:

- посмотрите на варианты вопросов, предложенных системой (прямо в интерфейсе показаны похожие вопросы)
- вбейте ваш заголовок в поисковик

Если найдёте ответ в поисковике, но не на Stack Overflow, то можно опубликовать одновременно как вопрос так и ваше решение в виде ответа — [это явно приветствуется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Не стоит бояться вопросов-дубликатов — они могут служить вехами, которые помогут другим людям с похожей проблемой их найти. Разные люди могут по-разному одну и ту же проблему представлять — вопросы, помеченные дубликатами, позволяют использовать разные формулировки, накапливая ответы при этом в одном месте (что хорошо).

Если вы увидели *открытый* вопрос, который вы думаете является *точным* дубликатом уже существующего, то можно пометить тревогой [как @val упомянул](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3991/23044). Определить является ли вопрос точным дубликатом или нет требует хорошего знания предметной области — вопросы, которые звучат одинаково, могут иметь совсем разные решения и наоборот, вопросы, которые звучат совершенно по-разному, могут быть абсолютно одинаковыми по сути. Или вопросы, для которых сегодня один и тот же код может ответ дать, могут иметь другие отличающиеся  решения или их решения со временем по-разному могут эволюционировать. *Если сомневаетесь, просто оставьте ссылку на похожий по вашему мнению вопрос в комментарии.*

Связанный вопрос (примеры, когда язык формулировки вопроса сильно отличается от языка фактического решения): [Следует ли править неинформативные заголовки вопросов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1381/23044)

> что полезного можно сделать, и как именно это следует делать.

После [начального тура](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/tour), вы получаете знаки, как правило, за поведение, которое система рассматривает желаемым. При росте репутации (больше активности на сайте — больше репутации, как правило) становятся доступны новые возможности (привилегии) — [этот список](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) упоминает активности, ожидаемые от участника с соответствующим уровнем репутации.

Если не уверены в полезности поведения, посмотрите [справку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help), [faq](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq) и если ещё нет буквального такого вопроса как у вас, то задайте его на Мете (как вы правильно и сделали). Для синхронного общения, вы можете попробовать [чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ru.stackoverflow.com) (не знаю, насколько темы модерации там приветствуются).

Answer (score 8):

Воспользуйтесь поиском по сайту или столбцом "похожие" у самого вопроса.

Что делать с дублями? Пометьте их тревогой "должен быть закрыт" -> "этот вопрос уже задан и имеет решение".

Comment: поиск по сайту плохой. Иногда он не находит вопросы/ответы, когда даже буквальные ключевые слова используешь при поиске, которые точно известно есть в сообщении. Можно обычный веб-поиск использовать (возможно с модификатором: site:ru.stackoverflow.com)