# Каков порядок создания канонических вопросов?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, вопросы

Коллеги, а каким образом принято в сообществе создавать канонические вопросы? Поискал на мете и в справке - и вижу, что данный вопрос особо не регламентируется и хотелось бы понять, есть ли какие-то типовые рекомендации?

В частности меня интересуют следующие вопросы:

- Что такое канонический вопрос? У нас есть некоторые вопросы, которые всем известны, как "эталонные закрывашки", все они имеют метки [faq](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq), верно ли обратное, что вопрос отмеченный этой меткой является каноническим?
- Кто имеет право от лица сообщества объявлять вопрос каноническим? Нужен ли какой-то порог репутации, наличие золотого знака, собрание какого-то консилиума?
- Что делать, если на вопрос навешивают метку [faq](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq) без согласия сообщества?
- Канонический вопрос подразумевает, что вопрос задавался неоднократно, означает ли это что нужно искать самый первый вопрос каноническим? Выбирать какой-то из имеющихся? Возможно, стоит написать новый, с "чистого листа"?
- Нужно ли ответы на канонический вопрос делать общими?
- Нужно ли делать вопрос защищённым?

И вообще. Нужны ли нам вообще "канонические" вопросы и ответы в виде явно выделенных сущностей? Или это просто сленговый термин для "популярный вопрос с хорошими ответами"?

Меня интересуют ответы в общем виде, хотя вопрос появился по конкретному поводу:

Внутри некоторой метки (c#) один из пользователей осознал, что имеется некоторая тема, по которой причинам постоянно задаются сходные вопросы, при этом ни разу не был использован механизм дубликатов. Была попытка на базе нового вопроса (удачно простого и наглядного) написать эталонный ответ (в т.ч. - при помощи механизма конкурсов), а затем продубликатить все вопросы в теме к этому.

Уже в процессе подготовки вопроса другие участники начали задавать вопросы (скажем, "почему нужен был новый вопрос, ведь есть неплохие существующие"), что и послужило толчком к рассуждениям на эту тему.

Comment: Нужны ли нам вообще "канонические" вопросы и ответы в виде явно выделенных сущностей? Или это просто сленговый термин для "популярный вопрос с хорошими ответами"?

Comment: @PashaPash, С такой политикой - конечно нет. Мы же тут не базу вопросов/ответом создаём. Вики вообще фигню сделали, надо на каждый вопрос с разной последовательностью слов создавать отдельную страницу.

Comment: Думаю, термин «канонический вопрос» появился впервые [здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/162/10105).

Comment: @Other если честно - ничего не понял. с какой политикой? причем тут "не база вопросов и ответов"?

Comment: @PashaPash, Это ирония, сложное искусство. Позиционируют SO как базу вопросов/ответов. Для этого очень подходит формат "каноничныхъ вопросов" (вопрос, который хорошо задан и хорошо отвечен, на него можно закрывать другие вопросы по теме). Но у нас тут политика "не надо запрещать каждый раз задавать один и тот же вопрос, не надо гуглить, отвечай ещё раз в сотый раз!". И дубликаты не особо помогают, т. к. из-за их рудиментарного вкрапления, их система бесполезна. Всё ради новичков и трафика.

Comment: @PashaPash, нужны.

Comment: @Other ок, чем тут помогут "каноничные вопросы" (по сравнению с просто топовыми и популярными вопросами).?

Comment: @Qwertiy зачем?

Comment: @PashaPash, Новичкам? Получат ёмкий и развёрнутый ответ по проблеме. Старичкам? Не парится, отвечая в сотый раз на одно и то же.

Comment: @PashaPash топовый/популярный вопрос вполне может оказаться каноничным, только создавался он изначально как обычный вопрос, а не вопрос для закрытия 100500 типовых дубликатов

Comment: @Qwertiy т.е. давайте я прямо сформулирую вопрос: сейчас есть проблема - новички не могут найти существующие вопросы и постят новые. [Старички предпочитают не искать дубликаты](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7254/), и отвечают заново. Что показательно, даже вопрос, из-за которого этот топик на мете появился, получит ответ-копипасту с небольшими исправлениями (типа каноничный ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/829931/, такой же ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/795854/ того же автора. Чем поможет отметка "каноничности", поставленная на усмотрение (кого-то?) на новом вопросе?

Comment: @yolosora почему вам так принципиально, чтобы вопрос изначально создавался для закрытия дубликатов? нужна ли на таком вопросе дополнительная отметка "он создан не просто так, это не просто хороший вопрос, а именно для закрытия дубликатов"?

Comment: простой кейс. предположим, мы выделили 200 каноничных вопросов. поставили на них метки. приходит новичок, не гуглит, задает вопрос заново. что поменяется по сравнению с текущим "пришел кто-то, и, не заморачиваясь с поиском дубликата, еще раз ответил"? Ну да, где-то там на другом вопросе есть отметка каноничности. и что? как это влияет на процесс? Получим каноничные вопросы "не особо помогают, т. к. из-за их рудиментарного вкрапления, их система бесполезна". Заменили термин, проблема осталась.

Comment: @PashaPash, так я ж там писал [ответ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7255/178988) и [комментарий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7254/Ищете-ли-вы-дубликаты-вопроса-перед-написанием-ответа#comment29564_7267)

Comment: @PashaPash, Поэтому и нужен более комплексный подход. Помимо создания "каноничныхъ вопросов", нужно удобное представление их. Как возможный пример - на enSO делали что-то вроде учебника, в статьях подробно освещали разные аспекты бытия. Сделать там поиск и наделить даже сереброносцев по метке способностью дубликатить по теме (а то Grundy загнётся с такой нагрузкой). Это как вариант.

Comment: @Other ну да, нужно. но вот у нас опытные участники не хотят искать. на enSO делали учебник (документацию). и закрыли за невостребованностью. Проблема в том, что отвечающие действуют по принципу "если не знаю, есть ли дубликат, отвечаю". Не потому что "неудобно" или "нет системы поиска по дубликатам". Система отметки "популярных" вопросов есть. Ей не пользуются. Если бороть проблему - то надо сначала узнать, почему не пользуются. А не вводить еще один термин для "популярного вопроса".

Comment: @Qwertiy я обычно отмечаю как дубликаты то, на что я сам писал ответы. Или то, что мне хорошо запомнилось. От того, что введут "отметку каноничности" ни легче искать, ни лучше узнавать "есть ли дубликат" не станет. Поэтому я и спрашиваю - если нужна отметка - то зачем?

Comment: @PashaPash, ты спросил не нужна ли отметка, а нужны ли вопросы. А отметка уже есть - это faq-* метки.

Comment: @Qwertiy подразумевал отметку :)

Comment: @Qwertiy: возможен вопрос, а нужны ли мета-метки типа faq на вопросах. https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Comment: @PashaPash: я "опытный участник" (с беты) и поэтому могу сказать, что неквалифицированное "не хотят искать"--это неверно.  Дубликат это не "популярный" вопрос -- это вопрос с рабочим ответом, который также отвечает и на текущий вопрос. Это относительно высокая планка -- к примеру, чужой ответ, если я лично не тестировал, скорее всего дубликатом не станет -- не могу поручиться лично, что работает  или нет -- я видел неверные ответы с 100 положительных голосов¶ Если нет серьёзных оснований, следует предполагать добрые намерения: существуют реальные препятствия к закрытию вопросов как дубликатов.

Comment: @jfs да, согласен, "не хотят искать" немного неправильно - не хотел копипастить "предпочитают не искать дубликаты" из коммента выше. Скорее - "предпочитают" / "редко закрывают как дубликаты" как описание текущей ситуации, а не намерения участников. По разным причинам, от вполне обоснованного недоверия к качеству чужих ответов до просто личных предпочтений - "Если написание ответа занимает менее минуты - обычно просто пишу ответ, ...  Если не знаю [что дубликат есть], то не ищу, даже если предполагаю, что он есть." - https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7255/.

Comment: @jfs если есть реальные препятствия - нужно их как-то осознать и устранить (хотя бы те из них, которые устранимы - я не знаю, как устранить личное недоверие чужим ответам). Предлагаемый в вопросе регламент (faq-метки, принудительно общие вопросы, порог репутации?, блокировки?) - почти никак не обоснован. Это решение ради решения, без описания конкретной проблемы.

Comment: @PashaPash не думаю, что существует какая-то одна мера, которая решит проблему однотипных вопросов или что это вообще удовлетворительно решаемо в масштабах SO. Согласен, что бюрократию без явного анализа плюсов/минусов лучше не добавлять. Можно разные идеи пробовать: если кому-то нравится писать канонические вопросы/ответы, то  если процедуры не разводить то не вижу вреда (мой ответ говорит, что уже можно это делать). Величина пользы не очевидна—это скорее плацебо для дубликатов: больше психологическое влияние на авторов ответов, если это поможет им продолжать обычные ответы писать то это плюс

Answer (score 8):

Регламента действительно нет, есть только сложившаяся практика. *Пишу ответ как тот человек который принимал участие в складывании этой практики.*

---

И так, чем руководствовался лично я когда создавал кучу "канонических" вопросов?

У простых вопросов от новичков есть одна проблема: они перегружены лишними деталями. И эти детали мешают считать вопросы полными дубликатами. Лично я не могу проголосовать за закрытие вопроса "не работает Bootstrap Tooltips после загрузки через AJAX" как дубликата "почему перестают работать плагины jquery при бесконечной прокрутке" - мешают бесконечная прокрутка и Bootstrap.

Удалять лишние детали из вопроса - не вариант, они могут оказаться важны. К примеру, в [том самом вопросе про Bootstrap Tooltips](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/625732/178779) *внезапно* нашлось специфичное именно для Bootstrap Tooltips решение! Поэтому в таких случаях попросту приходится писать свой вопрос, с как можно более общей формулировкой.

---

Теперь отвечаю на вопросы. *Все ответы являются лишь моим мнением и могут не отражать мнения других участников.*

> Что такое канонический вопрос?

Это любой вопрос, на который дан канонический ответ. Канонический ответ - это очень подробный и хороший ответ, в котором обязательно содержится объяснение причин возникновения проблемы и приводятся разные способы решения (если они, т.е. разные способы, существуют в принципе).

> У нас есть некоторые вопросы, которые всем известны, как "эталонные закрывашки", все они имеют метки faq, верно ли обратное, что вопрос отмеченный этой меткой является каноническим?

Возможно, так и есть. Но не надо думать что навешивание метки делает вопрос каноническим, связь тут исключительно статистическая. Исходная причина появления как метки faq, так и канонического ответа одна - частые вопросы от новичков, что и дает высокую корреляцию.

> Кто имеет право от лица сообщества объявлять вопрос каноническим? Нужен ли какой-то порог репутации, наличие золотого знака, собрание какого-то консилиума?

Никто такого права не имеет. Вопрос становится каноническим если у него есть ответ подходящий под критерии.

> Что делать, если на вопрос навешивают метку faq без согласия сообщества?

Без согласия сообщества или без согласия конкретного участника?

В первом случае - тихо снять обратно, попытаться переубедить в комментариях или  позвать модератора.

Во втором случае - выяснить мнение сообщества, через комментарии, чат или мету.

В целом, то же самое что для любой другой метки - с поправкой на большое число заинтересованных участников.

> Нужно ли ответы на канонический вопрос делать общими?

Конечно же нет. Написание подробных ответов - тяжелый труд, и было бы странно запрещать вознаграждать его репутацией.

> Нужно ли делать вопрос защищённым?

Этот вопрос не имеет смысла потому что кнопка "защитить" сразу не появляется (по крайней мере, у обычных участников) - а у модераторов наверняка есть своя инструкция по применению этой кнопки, и никакого признака "каноничности" в ней точно не упомянуто.

Answer (score 5):

Можно обойтись без введения формального понятия "канонического" вопроса, мета-меток, особого регламента.

Если хотите задать вопрос и сами дать на него ответ, то *уже* можете это сделать. Это [явно приветствуется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Если хотите закрыть другие вопросы как дубликаты вашего, то это *уже* можно сделать, следуя обычной процедуре для дубликатов: если один ответ отвечает на оба вопроса, то вопросы могут быть дубликатами. Если возникнет сомнение насколько подходящим дубликатом является, то также в обычном порядке можно: если это новый вопрос, то автор может подчеркнуть разницу между вопросами, явно указав почему решение не подходит и/или если соглашение не достигнуто, то конкретный вопрос о дубликате, можно на Мете обсудить. [Как проверить, не является ли вопрос дубликатом?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3989/23044)

Используя [вкладку цитируемые](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=frequent) можно, не добавляя мета-меток типа `[faq]`, увидеть на какие вопросы часто ссылаются. Аналогично [вкладка голоса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes) позволяет популярные вопросы по данному критерию просмотреть. Можно уточнить критерии поиска, к примеру, используя метки, ключевые слова. Опять такие нет необходимости явно добавлять метку `[популярный-вопрос]`. Ещё: [View Most Popular Questions by favorite count / views / votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/29405/137096)

То есть вопрос часто задаваемый не потому что кто-то faq метку добавил, а потому что его часто задают и соответственно много дубликатов уже есть. [How to organize the finding or writing and advertise the existence of canonical questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308371/4279)