# Задавить своим авторитетом?

Tags: обсуждение, комментарии, нормы-поведения

Относительно давно расположился на сайте, как на домашней странице, так как часто приходиться искать и иногда задавать вопросы. В общем, есть некоторое представление, как работает сайт и какие здесь нормы поведения.

Сегодня произошла очень странная ситуация. 
Задав очередной [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/928290/) удалился по своим делам, а по возвращению нашёл внутри вопроса претензию, якобы вопрос дублирует другой [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/608863/). 
Я просмотрел вопрос, затем ответ, и да, действительно, ответ очень похож на тот, который мне дали в моём вопросе. Но сама формулировка вопроса и код — отличаются и не очевидны. Возможно, специалист высокого уровня увидит и скажет "да тут всё и так ясно", но если бы я первой ссылкой его в гугле увидел, то прошёл бы мимо, так как не мой случай, даже близко.

После ответа на мой вопрос, и сравнения вопросов, да, действительно, есть некоторые
похожие отсылки, но все они идут из одной спецификации, с этим не поспоришь. Т.е. для меня это были два разных вопроса.

Вернёмся к теме авторитетов. [Человек](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/183394/vlad-from-moscow), написавший в комментариях, как я понял, имеет некоторый авторитет. Он высказал своё мнение, я парировал, так как считал по-другому. Его основным аргументом было, то, что ответы очень похожи, с этим я не спорил. **Но то, что ответы похожи, это не означает что суть и сами вопросы похожи.**

Я хотел на этом прекратить, но человек стремился мне доказать свою точку зрения другими словами, тоже самое делал и я. Но тут вскрылась интересная особенность - он пытался задавить меня своим авторитетом. Он разбирается лучше, и другие точки зрения не могут быть приняты.

Дальше в лес — больше дров. Переход на личности и сквозные упоминания о моём недостаточном развитии. Не спорю, я ещё юн и в программировании меньше 3ёх лет, но даже это не даёт право так писать. Мы спорили не о фундаментальных вещах программирования, а о похожести вопросов, где у каждого **МОЖЕТ** быть своё мнение.

В комментариях под [первым](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/928290/) вопросом всё видно. На мой взгляд, неверно опускаться до таких споров. Вы пометили, что вопрос дублирующий, значит придёт модератор и также проверит. Также можно вступить в дискуссию и попробовать человека самому наставить на путь истинный, если это действительно поможет. Но не более, зачем переходить границы и пытаться втиснуть свои слова за абсолютную истину придавливая авторитетом? Возможно, такое притеснение авторитетом не такая уж и большая проблема и я сейчас веником пыль поднимаю.

Тем не менее, хочу выслушать Ваше мнение на эту конкретную ситуацию.

p.s. комментарии модераторы подчистили спустя некоторое время. По случайности, я сохранил часть комментариев в виде скриншота для истории.

p.s.s. 
1) На данный момент (**07.01.2018**) вопрос был помечен дубликатом. Отдельно хочу подметить, что сейчас тему интерпретировали совершенно по-другому. **От изменения вопроса, меняется отношение к вопросу.** В комментариях меня даже начали утешать тем, что дубликаты это нормально. Для тех, кто открыл этот вопрос на этапе дубликата, попрошу прочитать скриншот. На том этапе присутствует часть истории.

2) Вопрос можно считать исчерпанным. Даже если и людей, которые были согласны, что на ruSOF присутствует "давка авторитетом", о которой я писал выше, то сейчас мой вопрос был помечен дубликатом. Может кто-то по "фану поставил", кто-то действительно в нём увидел дубликат, но то, что он отличается от другого вопроса - для меня останется правдой. Прошу не считать этот вопрос жалобой. Я хотел поднять очень важную тему, где люди, возможно, **могут ошибаться**, **но их авторитет не позволяет им этого увидеть.**

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пишите модераторам, спасибо за то что поделились. Мнение, конечно ситуация не нормальная.

Comment: imho закрытие вопроса как дубликата, вообще неправильная фича, поэтому надо бороться с этим правилом сайта, а не с конкретным  чудаком.

Comment: @avp опишите соответствующее предложение на Мете, лучше сразу на MSE. Что тут в комментариях попусту распыляться. Послушаем мнение других.

Comment: @älёxölüt, мнение активистов мне хорошо известно, тут же я просто просветил человека, что существуют и другие взгляды на текущие правила сайта

Comment: @avp это не повод оставлять эту проблему вариться в своей голове, выскажитесь как положено в формате QA. Пополните базу знаний, а не комментариев, подлежащих удалению. Это же не сложно.

Comment: @älёxölüt, пустое это (пока) занятие. Идея должна созреть в массах, тогда ее и стоит начать проводить в жизнь

Comment: @avp так задайте вопрос, это способ донести идею до масс. Самый подходящий. Чего стесняться.

Comment: @älёxölüt, а я не стесняюсь, просто не хочу в очередной раз расстраиваться

Comment: @avp значит, вы просто недостаточно верите в свою идею. Но от периодического упоминания в комментариях к разрозненным вопросам солидарных с вами вряд ли возрастет количество.

Comment: @älёxölüt, в то, что подобное предложение сейчас пройдет, не верю (вы правы). А про солидарных -- как известно "капля камень точит"

Comment: @avp согласен. А начать нужно с Grundy. Нужно отобрать у него закрывашку. А то столько бедных джаваскриптеров пострадало :D

Comment: Не увидел в комментариях ни давления авторитетом, ни перехода на личности. Там уже поработали модераторы?

Comment: @Suvitruf Изменил метки, так как закрытие и дубликаты — предыстория, контекст, но не суть самого вопроса. Здесь вопрос больше про нормы поведения и допустимость подобного рода комментариев.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как проверить, не является ли вопрос дубликатом?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3989/23044)

Comment: Вы тут описали какие то переходы на личности в комментариях, и приложили ссылку на вопрос, в котором 4 комментария. Я что то упустил, или же я попросту не вижу где в предложении `"Ваш вопрос абсолютно дублирует тот вопрос, который я указал. Разница лишь в типе бинарного оператора - вместо умножения используется сложение."` описанные Вами вещи?

Comment: Добавлю что Ваш коментарий в ответ является более провокационным

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach Там уже всё оскорбительное подчистили.

Comment: @avp а я считаю, что дубликаты - это главная фича SO. Если их запретить, то начнется привычное формуное "на этот вопрос уже отвечали, сколько можно, откуда вы лезите"...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а вот таким --  `"на этот вопрос уже отвечали, сколько можно, откуда вы лезите"` -- активные борцы за чистоту могли бы указывать, что так поступать нехорошо (бинайс -)). Все же, ничто ведь не мешает, указав, что существует дубликат оставить и этот вопрос вместе с возможностью отвечать на него. Поймите, люди часто идут на форумы-сайты для диалога, для общения с живыми коллегами по поводу **своей проблемы**. Кому это не нужно, тот просто ищет в интернете. Отсылка к существующему и уже отвеченному вопросу (даже если он решает проблему) вместе с закрытием твоего -- обижает.

Comment: Не стоит относиться к закрытию как дубля как к оскорблению :) - это всего лишь указание, где искать ответ на ваш вопрос, не более того. Спорить стоило бы, если бы ответ в первом вопросе не подходил к вашему. P.S. Да и суть этих вопросов по сути (простите за каламбур) если и не одинакова, то **очень** близка.

Comment: @Harry это эффект Барбары Стрейзен вроде бы называется. Вопрос закрыли, т.к. пришло достаточное количество людей, которые может и не большинство, но их хватило для закрытия вопроса. Вы совершенно не так интерпретировали суть: мне не болит душа от того, что он дубликат или нет. Если Вы внимательно прочитаете суть текста, то заметите, что говорится о том, что человек давит авторитетностью своего мнения. Но к сожалению, нашлось ещё таких 4 сторонника, которые с ним согласились, и в конце вопрос был помечен дубликатом. Очень обидно, что теперь это выглядит как моя обида. Говорил о другом.

Comment: @KeyJibo Значит, я не так вас понял.

Comment: @avp вопрос интерпретировал какой-то участник, который совершенно не разобрался в вопросе и ради очков репутации поспешил исправить на "своё". Я вернул к первоначальному варианту. Можно ли как-то посмотреть кто изменил?

Comment: @Harry Изменения в вопрос внёс человек, который не разобрался в теме вопроса, тем самым посеял двусмысленность, где я якобы жалуюсь на то, что закрыли вопрос. Перечитайте вопрос, я дополнил внизу актуальной информацией.

Comment: @Kromster Вы сделали обратное тому, о чём я говорил. У Вас очень много рейтинга, примерно, в 29 раз относительно меня. Но тем не менее, изменить тему вопроса, где говорится об авторитете, что людям свойственно ошибаться и они сами не могут заметить, как переходят границы допустимого, чтобы доказать свою правоту, Вы меняете тему на "Мой вопрос посчитали дубликатом другого и попытались задавить авторитетом. Ваше мнение?". Если Вы прочитаете вопрос, то суть не в жалобе, что вопрос, возможно, дубликат. Прошу, будьте более внимательны при изменениях. Спасибо, что уделили время.

Comment: @KeyJibo вот вы только что своим авторитетом "автора вопроса" задавили меня и правку. И все к вам просьба, дайте вопросу более описательное название. Сейчас название вопроса "ни о чем".

Comment: @Kromster Извините, если Вам так показалось, этого делать я ни чуть не хотел. Меня немного ошеломило столь кардинальное изменение темы вопроса, что повлияло на настроение тематики в корне. Текущее название очень хорошо отражает настроение и направление моих мыслей при написании, также даёт ответ на вопрос, ведь моя статья - это раскрытие вопроса. Этот пласт текста писался исключительно под вопрос, если его изменить, то нужно изменять и весь пост. Если в этом нет крайней необходимости, я бы хотел оставить таким, какой он есть сейчас. Благодарен за критику.

Comment: Если скриншот - это все, о чем вы говорите, то мне не ясно, где там переход на личности? Вы же считаете оскорблением если вам кто то говорит, что вы чего то не понимаете? И где давление авторитетом? Я этого тоже не увидел. По моему вы раздуваете драму на ровном месте.

Comment: @tym32167 Обратите внимание на послесловие. Сейчас вопрос уже исчерпан и не актуален за отсутствием всего диалога и пометкой "дубликат". По-вашему может быть.

Comment: Да я прочитал вопрос и послесловия, и, так как вся ваша переписка не сохранилась, сужу только по тому, что есть. А в том, что есть, я никаких проблем не вижу. У меня [бывали похожие дискуссии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/768523/179763) с другими участниками, это нормально, что то обсуждать и пытаться друг другу что-то доказать. Может, это и не эталон бинайса, но и, по моему мнению, не является чем то оскорбительным.

Comment: ну и по поводу `Я хотел поднять очень важную тему, где люди, возможно, могут ошибаться, но их авторитет не позволяет им этого увидеть.` - это какое имеет отношение вообще к вашей переписке с тем участником? Кто там прав, а кто нет - это большой вопрос, а если вы допускаете, что высокореповый участник не прав, допускаете ли вы, что сами тоже можете быть не правы? Сделали ли вы сами что то, чтобы избежать переходов на личности? Пытались ли дать понять оппоненту, что он вас оскорбил? Пробовали ли сами разрешить ваш конфликт?

Answer (score 24):

Комментарий вида "Возможный дубликат вопроса: ссылка" - это просто автоматический комментарий, который добавляется при голосовании за закрытие вопроса. Вопросы на сайте закрываются не модераторами, а [обычными участниками с достаточно высокой репутацией](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

Для закрытия вопроса нужно 5 голосов. В случае дубликата может быть достаточно одного золотого знака по метке. У проголосовавшего участника этого знака нет.

Сейчас на вашем вопросе один голос за закрытие, так что можете считать что пока предложение "это дубликат" никто не поддержал.

---

По поводу перехода на личности и оскорбления - просто ставьте на таких комментариях тревогу "оскорбительный", придут модераторы и наведут порядок.

Comment: Кстати, иногда эти золотые метки "давят". Смотришь - вроде и дубликат, а вроде и не совсем. Но если без метки как бы выставляешь вопрос на голосование - типа, взгляните, не дубликат ли? - то с золотом должен принимать решение единолично :(

Comment: @Harry Пусть введут механизм отказа от "золотого значка члена партии".

Answer (score 10):

Дубликат или не дубликат определяется одинаковостью *ответов* на вопрос на Stack Overflow. Вопросы-дубликаты не удаляются. Это позволяет накапливать разные решения одной и той же проблемы *в одном месте*, позволяя разным людям формулировать эту проблему по-разному и найти решение по разным ключевым словам в веб-поисковике.

"Авторитет" возможно коррелирует с правдой, но если комментарии переходят на личности, то нажмите  на иконку с флагом, чтобы привлечь внимание модераторов к возможной проблеме.